# Removing an item from the result if it has a particular parameter somewhere in the table

Tags: mysql, sql

I've been looking all around stack overflow and can't seem to find a question like this but its probably super simple and has been asked a million times. So I am sorry if my insolence offends you guys.

I want to remove an attribute from the result if it appears anywhere in the table.

Here is an example: I want display every team that does not have a pitcher. This means I don't want to display 'Phillies' with the rest of the results.

Example of table:

[image]

Here is the example of the code I have currently have where Players is the table.

```
SELECT DISTINCT team
FROM Players
WHERE position ='Pitcher' Not IN
    (SELECT DISTINCT position
     FROM Players)
```

Thanks for any help you guys can provide!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use NOT EXISTS() :

```
SELECT DISTINCT s.team
FROM Players s
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Players t
                 where t.team = s.team
                   and position = 'Pitcher')
```

Or with NOT IN:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.team
FROM Players t
WHERE t.team NOT IN(SELECT s.team FROM Players s
                    WHERE s.position = 'Pitcher')
```

And a solution with a left join:

```
SELECT distinct t.team
FROM Players t
LEFT OUTER JOIN Players s
 ON(t.team = s.team and s.position = 'pitcher')
WHERE s.team is null
```

Comment: Thank you for the easy to understand and quick response!

Answer (score 1):

Use `NOT EXISTS`

**Query**

```
select distinct team 
from players p
where not exists(
  select * from players q
  where p.team = q.team
  and q.position = 'Pitcher'
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way to approach this problem is to aggregate `players` over `team`:

```
select team
from players
group by team
having sum(case when position = 'Pitcher' then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

The big advantage is that you'd read the table only once.

Another advantage is that you can easily adjust the `HAVING` clause to have more elaborate queries, e.g. get all teams that have at least one catcher, two outfielders, and no pitcher.

Comment: It would be advisable though to have a teams table, so you wouldn't have to read all players everytime you wanted to know what teams existed. (You also wouldn't have to edit your constraints everytime a team gets added or deleted.) In that case you would simply select from teams with a [NOT] IN or [NOT] EXISTS clause on players (as the players table would only contain the team ID, not the team name then).